# Deserialization Avro by Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-platform, avro, apache-kafka-connect, dataflow

I Construct Processes that is below.

data producer -> kafka broker -> kafka Connect -> pub/sub -> dataflow -> Google Cloud Storage.

kafka connect's default configuration of key, value converter is Avro Convertor.
When I made dataflow on GCP, I made it by using 'gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Cloud_PubSub_to_GCS_Text'.
As It dosen't support Avro Convertion, Serialized data is seen on the Cloud Storage. It means I cannot see the right text data.

How can I deserialize the data that come through pub/sub.

I just want to see the data of text format on Google Cloud Storage.

--
I already have used 'PubsubToAvro.java' for test. And they still couldn't push text data to Cloud Storage.
Does it means I should make custom pipeline template of Cloud dataflow?
If so, How can I do that?

PubsubToText.java : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubsubToText.java

PubsubToAvro.java : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubsubToAvro.java

Comment: There's a bunch of missing information here: How did your producer serialize the data when it wrote to Kafka? What converter did you use from kafka connect to pub/sub (https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/concepts.html#connect-converters)? The converter will write the data from the serialized form in Kafka to whatever format you need to use for the Kafka Connect sink, in this case pub/sub.

Comment: 1. 'Kafka connect' serialize data. not by data producer.  2. Kafka connect's converter was avro converter. what I want to do is deserialize the data and store it on google storage.

Comment: You need to use the Confluent KafkaAvroDeserializer in your Sink Connector and that process needs to be able to reach the same schema registry that the producer is configured with

Comment: Btw, Kafka Connect's default values are actually JSONConverter https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/connect-distributed.properties#L30-L31

Comment: Also, you could try and build this PR to skip dataflow and pubsub completely. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/pull/128